# set location of uisearchbar in uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, tableview, navigationbar, searchbar, searchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to add a searchbar to my viewcontroller. There are many tutorials with tableviewcontrollers, but not viewcontrollers. My problem is (like multiple other questions here) when selecting the searchbar the navbar moves up and searchtableview overlaps, but searchbar does not move up.

If I try to add it programatically I can implement it to the table header with:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = mySearchBar;
```

In my UI there are buttons between the searchbar and tableview. I'd like the searchBar to be set right below the navigationBar. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *searchBar_con=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:your_frame];
    searchBar_con.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  UISearchBar *srchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 240 , searchBar_con.frame.size.height)];
srchBar.delegate = self;
    [searchBar_con addSubview:srchBar];

UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:srchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:searchBar_con];
```